# How is Ratio implemented in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is something I have been confused about for a while and I am not sure how I can learn more about it. Let's say I have the following program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- liftM read getLine
    y <- liftM read getLine
    print (x % y)
```

If I run this with the input `6` and `2`, it will print `3 % 1`.

At what point does the simplification happen (namely the division by the gcd)? Is it implemented in `show`? If so, then is the underlying representation of the rational still `6 % 2`? If not, then does `(%)` do the simplification? I was under the impression that `(%)` is a data constructor, so how would a data constructor do anything more than "construct"? More importantly, how would I actually go about doing similar things with my own  data constructors?

I appreciate any help on the topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Ratio` is actually implemented in [`GHC.Real`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#Ratio) (on GHC, obviously), and is defined as

```
data Ratio a = !a :% !a deriving (Eq)
```

The bangs are just there for strictness.  As you can see, the function `%` is not a data constructor, but `:%` is.  Since you aren't supposed to construct a `Ratio` directly, you use the `%` function, which calls reduce.

```
reduce ::  (Integral a) => a -> a -> Ratio a
{-# SPECIALISE reduce :: Integer -> Integer -> Rational #-}
reduce _ 0              =  ratioZeroDenominatorError
reduce x y              =  (x `quot` d) :% (y `quot` d)
                           where d = gcd x y
(%) :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Ratio a
x % y =  reduce (x * signum y) (abs y)
```

The rule is that if an operator starts with a colon `:`, then it is a constructor, otherwise it is just a normal operator.  In fact, this is part of the Haskell standard, all type operators must have a colon as their first character.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness it might be worth mentioning that a function like `%` that set ups invariants or otherwise processes arguments before handing them over to a data constructor is often called a ‘smart constructor’.

Answer (score 7):

You can just look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#Ratio) to see for yourself:

```
instance  (Integral a)  => Num (Ratio a)  where
    (x:%y) + (x':%y')   =  reduce (x*y' + x'*y) (y*y')
    (x:%y) - (x':%y')   =  reduce (x*y' - x'*y) (y*y')
    (x:%y) * (x':%y')   =  reduce (x * x') (y * y')
    negate (x:%y)       =  (-x) :% y
    abs (x:%y)          =  abs x :% y
    signum (x:%_)       =  signum x :% 1
    fromInteger x       =  fromInteger x :% 1 

reduce ::  (Integral a) => a -> a -> Ratio a
reduce _ 0              =  ratioZeroDenominatorError
reduce x y              =  (x `quot` d) :% (y `quot` d)
                           where d = gcd x y
```